# Open URL in certain Tab with Dojo

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have the following function where I attempt to load a specified url into a new or existing tab (contentPane), I have it working for the most part, however when an existing tab is specified the original url still gets reloaded instead of adding the new html, how can I accomplish the part where an existing tab is passed without having to remove the attribute refreshOnShow upon creating a new tab??

```
openTab = function(url,title, id){
    var tab = dijit.byId(id);
    var centerPane = dijit.byId('centerPane');

    if (tab){
       //if target container exists then let's load the url and add it to the container
        centerPane.selectChild(tab);
        $.get(url, function(data) {
          $('#'+id).html(data);

        });
        centerPane.selectChild(tab);


    } else {

        var newTab = new dijit.layout.ContentPane(
                {
              'title': title,
              href:url,
              closable:true,
              selected:true,
              parseOnLoad:true,
              preventCache:true,
              refreshOnShow:true
            }, id);
        centerPane.addChild(newTab);
        centerPane.selectChild(newTab);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how my updated function looks, it works for me:

```
    openTab = function(url,title, id){
        var tab = dijit.byId(id);
        var centerPane = dijit.byId('centerPane');
        if (tab){
           //if target container exists then let's load the url and add it to the container
            tab.href = url;
            tab.set('title',title);
            centerPane.selectChild(tab);
        } else {        
            var newTab = new dijit.layout.ContentPane(
                {
                  'title': title,
                  href:url,
                  closable:true,
                  selected:true,
                  parseOnLoad:true,
                  preventCache:true,
                  refreshOnShow:true
                }, id);
            centerPane.addChild(newTab);
            centerPane.selectChild(newTab);
        }


    };
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you are doing is basically saying, when this tab is re-opened, let me append my content, and dojo is saying, 'I just opened this tab, and refreshOnShow is true, so let me go get my content from the server again'.

I think the cleanest way to get around that is to do as you say and set refreshOnShow to false.  Why do you have it set to true, does the tab have content that needs to be refreshed consistently from the server?

If what you want is something like this (for an existing tab):

1. User clicks
2. Dojo goes and refreshes existing tab content
3. Your manual (jquery based) handler goes and gets some other content
   and appends it to (or otherwise uses it with) the content dojo
   automatically refreshed

Then you should be able to do something like this:

```
newTab.connect(newTab, 'onLoad', function(){
// do my stuff after the dojo content has loaded
})
```

Which just adds an event handler to the contentpane for your tab that fires after the tab has gone to the server for its content.

Comment: It seems that if I just set the **href** attribute like this **tab.href = url;** does the trick, however I cannot re-set the title for the existing tab by doing it the same way: **tab.title = title;**

Comment: Try using `tab.set('title','My Incredible Title')`